# Apple Music URL Scheme

Tags: url-scheme, itunes-store, apple-music

I need to know the URL Scheme of Apple Music to open a specific song. Up to now I was using the link like this:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/monsieur-cousteau/id496076893?i=496076903&uo=4
```

That link, was working perfectly in iTunes Store, but now is not working any more. That's because the link is opened by Apple Music, and it seems to work because it opens the album, but not the specific song.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The structure of the links has changed there is now a flag in there for the open method:

iTunes:

```
https://geo.itunes.apple.com/au/album/monsieur-cousteau/id496076893?i=496076903&app=itunes
```

Apple music:

```
https://geo.itunes.apple.com/au/album/monsieur-cousteau/id496076893?i=496076903&mt=1&app=music
```

Note the `app=` at the end

There is a link generator here: https://tools.applemediaservices.com/ but I would imaging that you are generating these from your own log of apple ID's yes?

Also you will need to change the store, I am `/au/` because I am in australia, these links don't always automatically forward the user and can give "Not available on your store" errors.

To get to a specific track you use this:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/au/album/monsieur-cousteau/id496076893?i=496076903&app=itunes&ign-mpt=uo%3D4#
```

Note the change in uo part, I am not sure how this particular part is generated as I got out of the industry a year ago but there is more information here: https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/tools_en.html unfortunately being I no longer work in the industry I am not classed as an affiliate any more.

Comment: Thank you so much! I check it in the first days after the release and I didn't find it. Thanks :)

Comment: Is there a way to generate below apple music url: `https://geo.itunes.apple.com/au/album/monsieur-cousteau/id496076893?i=496076903&mt=1&app=music`

As mentioned in post, earlier I used to generate it by creating search query like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26549356/4988884