# Get Apple Music playlist share URL programmatically by Swift

Tags: ios, swift, apple-music

When sharing playlist in Apple Music app via Email, you can get a URL like this

https://itunes.apple.com/jp/playlist/if-you-like...may-j./idpl.4299b4c5a42048bd850eca538e68ace2?l=en

You will also have an URL when sharing local created playlist.

I would like to know if it is possible to get the URL programmatically on iOS using Swift.

[Effort studied but failed to solve]

1. Related discussion using link maker does not solve the problem 
   [Apple Music URL Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194155/apple-music-url-scheme)
2. Query the playlist using: MPMediaQuery.playlists() and enumerated the returned playlist but cannot find any property showing the URL

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this is not possible. I believe the playlist does not have the `idpl` value until the user manually presses the share button in iTunes. And, there's nothing in the API to create one.

I set up a proxy and had a look at the requests iTunes makes.

I created a playlist in iTunes and added songs to the playlist.  Every song I added made several requests to various endpoints under:
`https://ld-6.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZDaap.woa/daap/update` No `idpl` value in any of the responses.

Then I manually hit the share button. A request is made to
`https://client-api.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStorePlatform.woa/wa/lookup` with the `idpl` in the URL.

Now when you add more songs to the playlist, the responses contain the `idpl`.

From that it seems that the `idpl` is created on the device when the user touches share.

Probably best to file a radar for Apple to add a share URL property to `MPMediaPlaylist`.

EDIT: I filed [a radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6105025847754752)